# Apply custom font to html in itextsharp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

I have code

```
FontFactory.Register(Server.MapPath("includes/fonts/Rockwell-Light.ttf"));
    StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();
    style.LoadTagStyle("div", "face", "customfont");
    style.LoadTagStyle("div","encoding",BaseFont.CP1250);


foreach (IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader("<div>" + getProductDescription((this.Product.Description != null) ? this.Product.Description : "") + "</div>"), style))
    {
        productDescCell.AddElement(element);
    }
```

my issue is could not apply font to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BaseFont rockwellBold = BaseFont.CreateFont(Server.MapPath("includes/fonts/") + "ROCKB.TTF", BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font rock_11_bold_header = new Font(rockwellBold, 11, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(190, 36, 34));
PdfPCell descHeadrCell = new PdfPCell();
descHeadrCell.AddElement(new Phrase("Demo"), rock_11_bold_header));
```

Comment: In which way does this answer relate to the question on how to *apply custom font to html*?

Comment: Rockwell is custom font, need was to apply this font to html in itextsharp for pdf generation. Hopefully this is fine enough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to implement custom fonts via HTML in iTextSharp using the following code:

**Step 1:** Copy your font files to a subdirectory of your website, for my purposes I used "/media/fonts"

**Step 2:** Register the directory using the code below:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(C.Server.MapPath("/Media/Fonts"));
```

**Step 3:** Loop through all of the fonts in the FontFactory object to get the font's name:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string fontname in FontFactory.RegisteredFonts)
        {

            sb.Append(fontname + "\n");

        }
```

**Step 4:** Add the font name via a font-family style attribute:

```
YOURDIVNAME.Attributes.Add("style", "font-family: brush script mt italic;");
```